# How do I schedule a task with Celery that runs on 1st of every month?

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks, scheduling, celery

How do I schedule a task with [celery](/questions/tagged/celery) that runs on 1st of every month?

Comment: Have you read http://celeryq.org/docs/reference/celery.schedules.html ?

Comment: @Deniz: Doesn't look like that covers DoM.

Answer (score 17):

Since Celery 3.0 the crontab schedule now supports `day_of_month`
and `month_of_year` arguments: http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules

Answer (score 10):

You can do this using [Crontab schedules](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) and you cand define this either:

- in your django **settings.py**:

```py
from celery.schedules import crontab

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'my_periodic_task': {
        'task': 'my_app.tasks.my_periodic_task',
        'schedule': crontab(0, 0, day_of_month='1'), # Execute on the first day of every month.
    },
}
```

- in **celery.py** config:

```py
from celery import Celery
from celery.schedules import crontab

app = Celery('app_name')
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    'my_periodic_task': {
        'task': 'my_app.tasks.my_periodic_task',
        'schedule': crontab(0, 0, day_of_month='1'), # Execute on the first day of every month.
    },
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to find documentation on exactly how the '0's are used (I guess they are positional, minute/hour and are not optional, but not seen this explicitly stated)

Comment: It's just an interface to linux contrab have a look here to better understand the parameters and how it works: https://linuxconfig.org/linux-crontab-reference-guide

Comment: when i added `crontab(0,0,day_of_month='1')` it seems to get executed every second.

Answer (score 0):

Use below `crontab` in your app.conf.beat_schedule(Celery Beat Scheduler):

```
crontab(hour=set_your_hours, minute=set_your_minutes, day_of_week="*",
        day_of_month=1, month_of_year="*")
```