# How can I schedule a task with Celery that runs at specific day of month?

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I try to use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4397530/how-do-i-schedule-a-task-with-celery-that-runs-on-1st-of-every-month#_=_) but with no success. How can I specify a day of month at which task should be executed? My solution was

```
class DayOfMonth(schedule):

    def __init__(self, day=1):
        self.day = day

    def is_due(self, last_run_at):
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        if now.month != last_run_at.month and now.day == self.day:
            return True, 3000
        return False, 3000

    def __eq__(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, DayOfMonth):
                return self.day == other.day and self.month == other.month
            return False
```

I try tu run it with django-celery, but I still receive error that run_every is not specified.

EDIT 1:

I run my task adding:

```
"my_task": {
        "task": "util.tasks.CeleryManagementCommand",
        "schedule": DayOfMonth(day=4),
        "args": ('my_task',),
    },
```

to `CELERYBEAT_SHEDULE` dict

EDIT 2:

When I specify run_every in **init** -> `self.run_every = None` I receive an error that None type object has no attribute total_seconds

Comment: Why don't you do it through cron job?

Comment: Can you show the code used to create a task?

Comment: Because I have to use celery for this

Answer (score 1):

If you subclass, and change the **init** you'd better make sure to call the parent's **init**.
I'm pretty sure this will fix your problem:

```
class DayOfMonth(schedule):

    def __init__(self, day=1, *args, **kwargs):
        super(DayOfMonth, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.day = day
```

If you check this, it will shed a light on the errors you've encountered:
https://github.com/ask/celery/blob/master/celery/schedules.py#L33

Comment: unfortunately this one didn`t help :(

Answer (score 1):

Best for you to include this in your celery.py file:

```
"schedule": corntab(day_of_month=4),
```

Also import the corntab:

```
from celery.schedules import crontab
```